# missing template arguments before and variable or field 'printVector' declared void

Tags: c++, c++11

I got these two errors and I can not figure it out. I basic hit a coders block.

variable or field 'printVector' declared void and missing template arguments before

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

void printVector(vector<string> vec);

int main() {

vector<string> ivec;


cout<<"Please your sequence of words and ctrl-z to stop"<<endl;
string input;

while(getline(cin, input)){
    ivec.push_back(input);
}

cout<<"Your input is: \n";

for(std::vector<string>::iterator it = ivec.begin(); it != ivec.end(); ++it ){
    cout<<*it<<"";
  }

cout<<"Your input changed to upper case: "<<endl;
printVector(ivec);
return 0;
}


void printVector(vector<string> vec){
for(auto &v: vec){
    for(auto &c: v)
        cout<<toupper(c)<<"";
    }

}
```

updated:

```
void printVector(vector<string> vec){


// process characters in s until we run out of characters or we hit a whitespace
for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end() && !isspace(*it); ++it)
        *it = toupper(*it);
```

}
Errors:

Invalid arguments '
Invalid arguments '

no matching function for call to 'toupper(std::basic_string&)'

Comment: You are missing to `#include <string>`.

Comment: void printVector(vector<string> vec){


 // process characters in s until we run out of characters or we hit a whitespace
 for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end() && !isspace(*it); ++it)
   *it = toupper(*it);

}                                                                                                              Errors: 
Invalid arguments '
Invalid arguments '
no matching function for call to 'toupper(std::basic_string<char>&)'

Comment: [`toupper()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) expects a `char` parameter, but you pass a `std::string` dereferenced from the iterator. If you want to convert every character contained in the string to upper case, you need to roll your own function for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
#include <string>
```

to your program.
Since `std:string` is not declared the compiler cannot recognise it as a valid template argument with `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: I thought that if you have using namespace std, you don't have to do   std::vector<std::string>

Comment: @TheChessDoctor No, the `using namespace std;` only provides you don't need to put the `std::` prefix. If you need to use `std::string` you need to include it's declaration from the mentioned header file.

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
int toupper(int)
#0 toupper(#0, const std::locale &)
int toupper(int)
' Vector.cpp /Vector/src line 51 Semantic Error
no matching function for call to 'toupper(std::basic_string<char>&)' Vector.cpp /Vector/src line 51 C/C++ Problem

Comment: @TheChessDoctor And what has this to do with your original question?